# What is the AccuRev command to get the Parent Stream name for the given Child stream

Tags: stream, parent, accurev

I would like to get the AccuRev command to get the Parent Stream for the given child stream.

For example, below is the stream structure

Parent Stream 1 --> Parent Stream 2 --> Child Stream 1 --> Child Stream 2

If I give the stream "Child Stream 1" it should return "Parent Stream 2"

Answer (score 3):

The command 'accurev show streams' will list the backing stream.

In your case:
accurev show -s "Child Stream 1" streams